# Sum of rows and sum of columns of particular ID in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table columns are domain, Prog_StdName, Jul, Aug, Sep, where Prog_StdName is dependent on domain, I have tried the following query to display unique data from the table as in the below image:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT domain, Prog_StdName
 FROM cf_1ls 
 WHERE ls_no = 1234
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap8U9.png)

I want to sum of columns (Jul+Aug+Sep) for each unique row for particular `ls_no = 1234` ID  as in the below image, for that I have the below query

```
SELECT `core`,`domain`, `Prog_StdName`, sum(Jul+Aug+Sep) as total 
FROM `cf_1ls`
GROUP BY domain
ORDER BY `id`
```

But is displays 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlWqE.png)

Comment: (Jul+Aug+Sep)? Wh*aaa*t?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to sum of columns (Jul+Aug+Sep) for each unique row for
>   particular ls_no = 1234 ID as in the below image, for that I have the
>   below query

If you want to sum the values in each row, then you don't need `group by`.  Just use `+`:

```
SELECT `core`,`domain`, `Prog_StdName`,(Jul+Aug+Sep) as total 
FROM `cf_1ls`
ORDER BY `id`
```

Comment: It displays entire table rows